# How to store jwt token securely that it cannot be accessed by client script in react js

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, cookies, jwt

I have an API that returns a cookie after login and this cookie needs to be stored in the client side securely that it cannot be accessed by client script for eg:

`document.cookie("token")` should not return.

In asp.net core web API application with razor pages and JavaScript, it can be done but in react I don't know how to go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: this might help https://medium.com/how-to-react/how-to-use-js-cookie-to-store-data-in-cookies-in-react-js-aab47f8a45c3

Comment: If it's stored client side, it can be accessed by a client script. You can't put something on my computer that I can't access. If there's something the client isn't allowed to see, keep it on the server.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton For example if I use HttpOnly cookie in Dotnet, client script cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

The API must issue an HTTP-only secure cookie. It should also use `SameSite=strict`, as a protection against [cross site request forgery](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). The React app then just makes plain Ajax requests and does not need to protect any secrets client side.

In effect the API is acting as a [Backend for Frontend](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2) to assist the SPA with its security. From a security viewpoint it is then equivalent to the security provided by Razor websites.